# How do I get vagrant halt to successfully shut down debian jessie vm on yosemite host?

Tags: linux, macos, debian, vagrant, virtualbox

Whenever I attempt to run vagrant halt, it says "default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM..." but eventually times out and says " default: Forcing shutdown of VM..." sometimes this works and sometimes it leaves the VM in running state, according to the VirtualBox UI.

Here are the details of the system:
Host: OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite, Virtual Box 5.0.4, w/extension pack, Vagrant 1.7.4
VM: Debian Jessie 8.2.0 64bit, 2 GB Ram

Help! It seems like vagrant halt should be able to gracefully stop the VM?

Comment: do you have left over processes blocking the shut down ? can you run from the VM `sudo shutdown -h now` and see if it fails or always run -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in vagrant, here is the pull request that fixed it:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/6315

Version 1.7.5 will include this fix.